# What is the difference between np.sum and np.add.reduce?

Tags: python, numpy

What is the difference between `np.sum` and `np.add.reduce`?
While [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) are quite explicit:

> For example, add.reduce() is equivalent to sum().

The performance of the two seems to be quite different: for relatively small array sizes `add.reduce` is about twice faster.

```
$ python -mtimeit -s"import numpy as np; a = np.random.rand(100); summ=np.sum" "summ(a)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.11 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s"import numpy as np; a = np.random.rand(100); summ=np.add.reduce" "summ(a)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.81 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit -s"import numpy as np; a = np.random.rand(1000); summ=np.sum" "summ(a)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.78 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s"import numpy as np; a = np.random.rand(1000); summ=np.add.reduce" "summ(a)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.5 usec per loop
```

For larger array sizes, the difference seems to go away:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s"import numpy as np; a = np.random.rand(10000); summ=np.sum" "summ(a)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.7 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s"import numpy as np; a = np.random.rand(10000); summ=np.add.reduce" "summ(a)"
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.2 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Short answer: when the argument is a numpy array, `np.sum` ultimately calls `add.reduce` to do the work.  The overhead of handling its argument and dispatching to `add.reduce` is why `np.sum` is slower.

Longer answer:
`np.sum` is defined in [`numpy/core/fromnumeric.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py).  In the definition of `np.sum`, you'll
see that the work is passed on to `_methods._sum`.  That function, in [`_methods.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/_methods.py), is simply:

```
def _sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
    return um.add.reduce(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
                            out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
```

`um` is the module where the `add` ufunc is defined.

Comment: If you're still using 1.6.x, the details are different but the overall reason is the same - the overhead of `np.sum` calling through to `np.add.reduce` dominates the time spent in `np.add.reduce` itself.

Answer (score 16):

There is actually one difference that might bite you if you were to blindly refactor from one to the other:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(4).reshape(2, 2)
>>> 
>>> np.sum(a)
6
>>> np.add.reduce(a)
array([2, 4])
>>>
```

The `axis` default values are different!

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in the title, simply: When working with matrices,
you will find an important distinction between the two functions:

`np.sum` (without specifying the axis) will return the sum of all elements in the matrix.

`np.add.reduce` (without specifying the axis) will return the sum along axis=0.
That is, add.reduce(a) is equivalent to sum(a, axis=0)

However, both will return the same if you specify the axis.
I'm posting as answer because I don't have enough rep to comment.

Answer (score 1):

`np.add.reduce()` is useful if you have an array of numpy arrays. Consider the following example:

```
import numpy as np
arr = [np.array([2, 2]), np.array([0, 3]), np.array([4, 8])]
res = np.add.reduce(arr)
```

This will produce `res = array([ 6, 13])`.

It is the same as

```
import numpy as np
import functools
arr = [np.array([2, 2]), np.array([0, 3]), np.array([4, 8])]
res = functools.reduce(np.add, arr)
```