# np.sum and np.add.reduce - in production, what do you use?

Tags: python, numpy

As a background, please read this quick post and clear answer:
[What is the difference between np.sum and np.add.reduce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420097/what-is-the-difference-between-np-sum-and-np-add-reduce)

So, for a small array, using `add.reduce` is faster. Let's take the following code which I experimented with for learning, that sums a 2D array:

```
a = np.array([[1,4,6],[3,1,2]])
print('Sum function result =', np.sum(a))

# faster for small array - 
# print(np.add.reduce(a))

# but the only reduces dimension by 1. So do this repeatedly. I create a copy of x since I keep reducing it:
x = np.copy(a)
while x.size > 1:
    x = np.add.reduce(x)

print('Sum with add.reduce =', x)
```

So, the above seems like overkill -  I assume it's better to just use `sum` when you don't know the size of your array, and definitely if it's more than one dimension. Does anyone use `add.reduce` in production code if your array isn't obvious/small? If so, why?

Any comments for code improvisation are welcome.

Comment: Voting to close. This question is prone to discussions without real answer. If it bothers you, write a wrapper `sumSum` - test the np-array size and dimensions and use the correct one. Do some testing beforehand to get the break-even point of sum that calls add.reduce or add.reduce directly...

Comment: Good point. Thanks for your recommendation. It doesn't bother me, I'm just learning Numpy and Pandas and noted that one was faster than the other, but I realize that there isn't much importance here. Happy to delete this question if I get more comments to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think I've used `np.add.reduce` when `np.sum` or `arr.sum` would do just as well.  Why type something longer for a trivial speedup.

Consider a 1 axis sum on a modest size array:

```
In [299]: arr = np.arange(10000).reshape(100,10,5,2)

In [300]: timeit np.sum(arr,axis=0).shape
20.1 µs ± 547 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [301]: timeit arr.sum(axis=0).shape
17.6 µs ± 22.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [302]: timeit np.add.reduce(arr,axis=0).shape
18 µs ± 300 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [303]:
```

`arr.sum` is fastest.  Obviously it beats `np.sum` because there's one less level of function call.  `np.add.reduce` isn't faster.

The `ufunc.reduce` has its place, especially for `ufunc` that don't have the equivalent of `sum` or `prod`.  (seems that I commented about this recently).

I suspect you'll find more uses of `np.add.at` or `np.add.reduceat` than `np.add.reduce` in SO answers.  Those are `ufunc` constructs that don't have a method equivalent.

Or search for a keyword like `keepdims`.  That's available with all 3 constructs, but almost all examples will be using it with `sum`, not `reduce`.

When I was setting up those tests, I stumbled on a difference I wasn't aware of:

```
In [307]: np.add.reduce(arr).shape    # default axis 0
Out[307]: (10, 5, 2)
In [308]: np.sum(arr)     # default axis None
Out[308]: 49995000
In [309]: arr.sum()
Out[309]: 49995000
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all this great detail - I learnt a lot from your reply as it covers other functions I didn't look into yet. Thanks a lot :)