# `numpy.sum` vs. `ndarray.sum`

Tags: python, performance, numpy

For a 1-D `numpy` array `a`, I thought that `np.sum(a)` and `a.sum()` are equivalent functions, but I just did a simple experiment, and it seems that the latter is always a bit faster:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.arange(10000)

In [3]: %timeit np.sum(a)
The slowest run took 16.85 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.46 µs per loop

In [4]: %timeit a.sum()
The slowest run took 19.80 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.25 µs per loop
```

Why is there a difference? 
Does this mean that we should always use the `numpy.ndarray` version of functions like `sum`, `mean`, `std`, etc.?

Comment: Mostly you are seeing a difference in one level of function redirection.  In most of these cases the function version redirects the task to the method (look at the code).  Don't worry about speed here - use the form that makes your code clearest (to you and your readers).  You must use the function version if your input might be a list instead of an array.

Comment: Last year I answered something similar [np.sum and np.add.reduce - in production, what do you use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48515725/np-sum-and-np-add-reduce-in-production-what-do-you-use)

Answer (score 3):

I'd imagine it is becasue `np.sum()` and the like <del>needs to explicitly convert the inputs to `ndarray` first (using `np.asanyarray`)</del> [checks a few other `.sum` functions](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L1778-L1882) before settling on the `ndarray.sum` method in order to allow operation on lists, tuples, etc.

On the other hand, `ndarray.sum()` is a method of the `ndarray` class and thus doesn't need to do any checking.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought the conversion should just boil down to a simple check if `a` is already an array, and shouldn't involve explicit copying, right?

Comment: You'd think so, but it actually seems to deduce that `a` is an `ndarray` [only if nothing else's `.sum` method works](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.14.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L1778-L1882), including generators and the old `numeric` `multiarray`

Comment: Which makes sense, you don't want to convert a big linked list to `ndarray` if you don't have to

Comment: @Hilbert: No copy is made - the overhead is O(1), not O(N).

Comment: @DanielF: The fact that generators are checked there is bizarre and undocumented - I've opened  https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10652

Comment: @Eric My guess is that is to maintain the functionality of the standard `sum` in case you do `from numpy import *` or `from pylab import *`.