# universal function concept and notation in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc

I'm learning numpy package, and I've found this code example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
np.add.reduce(a)
```

The thing I'm unable to understand is the dot notation:

```
np.add.reduce(a)
```

in contrast with, for example

```
np.add(a,5)
```

I understand what add and reduce do, but what is add? What is reduce?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420097/what-is-the-difference-between-np-sum-and-np-add-reduce

Comment: @Inder Thank you, I actually learned that something new when *answering* a question! "add.reduce is about twice faster" (than sum)

Comment: `np.add` is a `ufunc`.  `reduce` is a method of that function.

Answer (score 1):

"Reduce" is a general concept, and I found a decent definition at https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

> Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of sequence, from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.

Numpy's ufunc reduce is documented at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html

> Reduces a’s dimension by one, by applying ufunc along one axis.

So `np.add.reduce(a)` (also known as `np.add.reduce(a, axis=0)`) will call `np.add` on `a[0]` and `a[1]`, then add the result to `a[2]`, etc. until it incorporates all `len(a)` elements.

Result: `array([5, 7, 9])`

---

`np.add(x, y)` is basically `x + y`. `np.add.reduce(a, axis=0)` is basically `np.sum(a, axis=0)`.

---

`np.add.reduce(a, axis=1)` adds `a[:, 0]` to `a[:, 1]`, then adds result to `a[:, 2]`, and so on.`

Result: `array([ 6, 15])`