# Are np.sum and np.add.reduce actually equivalent?

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way to guarantee that calling `np.sum(A)`, `np.add.reduce(A)`, and `A.sum()` will generate precisely the same value (in an `==` sense) for a one-dimensional floating point numpy array `A`?

From the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) of `np.ufunc.reduce`, it's explicitly stated that

> add.reduce() is equivalent to sum()

and further specified that `reduce` is *left-to-right associative*; specifically, that 'op.reduce produces results equivalent to' the following code:

```py
r = op.identity # op = ufunc
for i in range(len(A)):
  r = op(r, A[i])
return r
```

This would be seem to be the expected behavior, as CPython's built-in `sum()` and `functools.reduce()` also explicitly guarantee left-to-right evaluation, which is relevant since floating point addition isn't a mathematically associative operation.

However, looking at the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) of `np.sum` (which also helpfully mentions that `add.reduce` and `ndarray.sum` are equivalent methods) there is a seemingly contradictory note (emphasis mine):

> For floating point numbers the numerical precision of sum (and `np.add.reduce`) is in general limited by directly adding each number individually to the result causing rounding errors in every step. However, **often numpy will use a numerically better approach (partial pairwise summation)** leading to improved precision in many use-cases.

The description of when the 'pairwise summation' algorithm is preferred implies that a call to `np.sum(A)` as above would give a different evaluation order than `np.add.reduce(A)`, and therefore a potentially different result. It's not at all clear to me whether this behavior can be disabled, if disabling the behavior would interfere with numpy's vectorization ability, and where in the source code this decision takes place (or even which functions are affected).

For some background knowledge, it was helpful to look at this question from 2013: [What is the difference between np.sum and np.add.reduce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16420097/what-is-the-difference-between-np-sum-and-np-add-reduce). However, that post (and all others I've seen) was asking about the performance differences, and the top answer by Warren Weckesser states that

> when the argument is a numpy array, np.sum ultimately calls add.reduce to do the work.

While I'm not asking about the performance comparison, this (possibly outdated) answer added even more mystery, since it would also seem to imply that `np.add.reduce` should always give identical output to `np.sum`, and therefore that the documentation for `ufunc.reduce` is incorrect in stating that it produces results equivalent to left-to-right associativity since pairwise-summation could occur.

My goal isn't to sum floating point numbers in the most precise way, but rather to ensure that the value I get from using numpy to sum a one-dimensional, float64 numpy array `A`, evaluates as `==` to CPython's left-to-right `sum(A)`. As such, I'm not exactly asking about the trade-offs of using either function, but about information regarding the actual evaluation order for these functions on the current version  of numpy, given that the documentation mentions they are all 'equivalent' while also implying that they could give unequal results.

Comment: docs have a link to [source], https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.21.0/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L2123-L2260

Comment: @hpaulj Perhaps I should have mentioned in the post that I've spent several hours reading the source code for numpy's ufunc implementations on Github and even found the diff where that quoted comment was added. I'm now fairly sure that the behavior of all 3 methods is exactly equal, and that no guarantees about reordering are offered. I also suspect that figuring out what exactly that behavior is (and how to modify it) requires a deep understanding of NumPy's internals, specifically how iteration and threading are implemented in C.

Comment: There are functions for doing `_pairwise_sum`  in `numpy/core/src/umath/loops_utils.h.src`, which can be called from `numpy/core/src/umath/loops_arithm_fp.dispatch.c.src` and `numpy/core/src/umath/loops.c.src`  This is all low level `ufunc` coding.